# How to ignore first element in xpath

Tags: xpath

How can I ignore first element and get rest of the elements?

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">some link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link i want to find</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you define what the "first element" is?  From the example XML the first element is the `ul`, or if you mean from the `ul` the first element is `li`, or do you want to select all `a` elements then skip the first one of those?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

if you want to ignore the "first" element only then:

```
//li[position()>1]
or
(//a)[position()>1]
```

if you want the last only (like your example seems to suggest):

```
//li[last()]
or
(//a)[last()]
```

Comment: Remember that indexes in XPath are 1-based, not 0-based. So the expression `a[position()>1]` returns all `a` elements except the first one.

Comment: position() returns the position of the context element.  In the XPATH provided, the position of each `a` would equal 1 AND last() and return each of the `a` elements, not skipping the first.

Comment: In order to get `position()` to evaluate as expected, you need to wrap the selection of elements in parentheses to group them in a node-set and *then* apply the predicate filter on position (i.e. (`//a)[position()>1]` and `(//a)[last()]` )

Comment: @isme... yes i know it's 1 based, but i was puzzled by the question because he says he wants to ignore the first element, but the example suggests he'd only want the last one

Comment: -1 This answer is wrong in the context of the question. There is no `//a[position()>1]` in the example, and `//a[last()]` has three matches. Did you test your XPath before posting it?

Comment: @Tomalak you're right! i did it wrong, i should be using "li" instead if "a" i'll to the adjustment... sorry about that

Comment: @Mads Hansen: you're also right i adjusted my response according to your comments thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You can use `position()` to skip over the "first" one, but depending on which element you are interested in and what the context is, you may need a slight variation on your XPATH.

For instance, if you wanted to address all of the `li` elements and get all except the first, you could use:

```
//li[position()>1]
```

and it would work as expected, returning all of the `li` elements except for the first.

However, if you wanted to address all of the `a` elements you need to modify the XPATH slightly.  In the context of the expression `//a[position()>1]` each one of the `a` elements will have a `position()` of 1 and `last()` will evaluate to true.  So, it would always return every `a` and would not skip over the first one.

You need to wrap the expression that selects the `a` in parenthesis to group them in a node-set, then apply the predicate filter on position.

`(//a)[position()>1]`

Alternatively, you could also use an expression like this:

```
//a[preceding::a]
```

That will find all `a` elements except the first one (since there is no `a` preceding the first one).