# Scraping page with correct xpath using Mechanize and nokogiri

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I am trying to access data contained in a table that is itself contained in a table with `class ='L1'`.
So basically my html structure is like this:

```
<table class="L1">
  <table>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><a href="">data</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><a href="">data</a></td>
    </tr>
    ...ect...ect
  </table>
</table>
```

I need to catch the data contained in a all `<a> </a>` that are in the second   contained in `<tr> </tr>` but only starting with the second `<tr>` of the table.

So far I came up with that:

```
html_body = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
links = html_body.css('.L1').xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]")
```

But seems to me that this doesn't express the fact that I want to start only after the second `<tr>` (second `<tr>` included?
What would be the right code to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [position()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2634258/802618) to select the later elements that you want.

```
html_body = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
links = html_body.css('.L1').xpath("//table/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[2]/a[1]")
```

As the comments on that SO answer say, remember XPath counts from 1, so `>1` skips the first `tr`.